# how to have a select query that generates host-guests table planed games?

Tags: sql, select

I have a table that keeps 16 football team name:

```
ID  Team Name
..  ..
8   MANUTD
..  
13  CHELSEA
..  ..
```

How can I have a second table by a select query that generates random games for each week of the season? Each team plays with others two times, 1st as host and 2nd as guest and obviously each team plays once in a week. Two teams never play two time with each other during a half season and next time they play in second season their position in two fields will be change as the host-gust order. How can I have such a select query?

**Table 2 - first half season game**

```
ID  Host    Guest   Result
..  ..  ..  ..      ..
..  MANUTD  CHELSEA ..
```

**Table 2 - 2nd half season game**

```
..  ..  ..  ..
..  CHELSEA MANUTD  ..
..  ..  ..  ..
```

Comment: You should consider creating the tables in http://sqlfiddle.com/ to encourage more responses

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

By now, I developed the creation of a single week calendar. Tomorrow I'll add the loop for the complete calendar:

```
DECLARE @CTR INT
DECLARE @HOST INT
DECLARE @GUEST INT
DECLARE @TEAMS TABLE (Ind INT, Name VARCHAR(50))
DECLARE @MATCHES TABLE (Ind INT, Host INT, Guest INT)

INSERT  @TEAMS (Ind, Name) VALUES ( 1, 'Arsenal')
INSERT  @TEAMS (Ind, Name) VALUES ( 2, 'Aston Villa')
INSERT  @TEAMS (Ind, Name) VALUES ( 3, 'Bournemouth')
INSERT  @TEAMS (Ind, Name) VALUES ( 4, 'Chelsea')
INSERT  @TEAMS (Ind, Name) VALUES ( 5, 'Crystal Palace')
INSERT  @TEAMS (Ind, Name) VALUES ( 6, 'Everton')
INSERT  @TEAMS (Ind, Name) VALUES ( 7, 'Leicester')
INSERT  @TEAMS (Ind, Name) VALUES ( 8, 'Liverpool')
INSERT  @TEAMS (Ind, Name) VALUES ( 9, 'Manchester City')
INSERT  @TEAMS (Ind, Name) VALUES (10, 'Manchester Utd')
INSERT  @TEAMS (Ind, Name) VALUES (11, 'Newcastle')
INSERT  @TEAMS (Ind, Name) VALUES (12, 'Norwich City')
INSERT  @TEAMS (Ind, Name) VALUES (13, 'Southampton')
INSERT  @TEAMS (Ind, Name) VALUES (14, 'Stoke City')
INSERT  @TEAMS (Ind, Name) VALUES (15, 'Sunderland')
INSERT  @TEAMS (Ind, Name) VALUES (16, 'Swansea City')
INSERT  @TEAMS (Ind, Name) VALUES (17, 'Tottenham')
INSERT  @TEAMS (Ind, Name) VALUES (18, 'Watford')
INSERT  @TEAMS (Ind, Name) VALUES (19, 'West Bromwich')
INSERT  @TEAMS (Ind, Name) VALUES (20, 'West Ham') 

SET @CTR = 0 

WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN
   SET @CTR = @CTR + 1
   SET @HOST = 0
   SET @GUEST = 0
   WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN
      SET @HOST  = FLOOR(RAND() * 20) + 1
      SET @GUEST = FLOOR(RAND() * 20) + 1
      IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Host  From @MATCHES WHERE Host  = @HOST ) AND
         NOT EXISTS(SELECT Host  From @MATCHES WHERE Host  = @GUEST) AND
         NOT EXISTS(SELECT Guest From @MATCHES WHERE Guest = @HOST ) AND
         NOT EXISTS(SELECT Guest From @MATCHES WHERE Guest = @GUEST) AND
         @HOST <> @GUEST BREAK
   END
   INSERT @MATCHES (Ind, Host, Guest) VALUES ( 1, @HOST, @GUEST)
   IF @CTR = 10 BREAK
END

SELECT A.Ind, B.Name, C.Name FROM @MATCHES A
JOIN @TEAMS B ON Host = B.Ind
JOIN @TEAMS C ON Guest = C.Ind
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this uses a few loops and table variables, it is not the most efficient solution for large sets. But if you are just doing this once with 16 teams, it works:

```
create table Teams (team varchar(5))
insert into Teams(team) values
('a'),
('b'),
('c'),
('d'),
('e'),
('f'),
('g'),
('h'),
('i'),
('j'),
('k'),
('l'),
('m'),
('n'),
('o'),
('p')
```

Use an exclusive cross join to create the unique matchups:

```
declare @Matchups table (home varchar(5), away varchar(5), orderNo float)
insert into @Matchups
select * from (
select x1.team as home, x2.team as away,RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) as orderNo from @x x1
cross join @x x2
where x1.tm <> x2.tm
) a

declare @half1 table (home varchar(5), away varchar(5), week int)
declare @matchup int = 15
declare @week int = 15
```

Create the first matchup then loop through the table, making sure no team plays twice in the same week and no matchup is duplicated

```
delete top(1) from @Matchups
output deleted.home,deleted.away,@week into @half1

set @matchup = @matchup - 1

while @week > 0
begin
    while @matchup > 0
    begin
        delete top(1) s
        output deleted.home,deleted.away,@week into @half1
        from @Matchups s
        where not exists (
                    select 1 from @half1 m
                    where ((m.away = s.away
                    or m.away = s.home 
                    or m.home = s.away
                    or m.home = s.home)
                    and week = @week)
                    or
                    (m.away = s.away
                    and m.home = s.home)
                    or
                    (m.away = s.home
                    and m.home = s.away)
                    )
        set @matchup = @matchup - 1
    end
    set @week = @week - 1
    set @matchup = 15
end

set @week = 15
set @matchup = 8
```

For the second half, just insert the values into the table in the reverse home/away order, then randomize the match.

```
declare @half2 table (home varchar(5), away varchar(5), week int)
while @week > 0
begin
    while @matchup > 0
    begin 
        insert into @half2
        select top 1 away,home,@week from 
        (select *,RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) as orderNo from @half1 h1
        where not exists (
                        select 1 from @half2 h2
                        where (h1.away = h2.away 
                        or h1.away = h2.home 
                        or h1.home = h2.away 
                        or h1.home = h2.home)
                        and week = @week)) a
        order by orderNo
        set @matchup = @matchup - 1
    end
    set @matchup = 8
    set @week = @week - 1
end


select *,1 as Half from @half1
union all
select *,2 as Half from @half2
```